# Make Jenkins get list of images from GCP and display as list

Tags: jenkins, groovy, gcloud

I'v been sending new versions of app in docker images to GCP Container Registry, now I wanted to create a jenkins job that when picked `Build with Parameters` gives you a list of let's say last 15 tagged images, and let's you choose which version of app to deploy - the entire logic how to deploy etc. I can handle, but I'v been thinking how to `live` display those versions, anyone have any idea ? I know about the `Active Choice Parameter` and there is a Groovy Script section - I used it before to list GIT Branches - but not sure how to authenticate to GCP and run

```sh
gcloud container images list-tags gcr.io/my/image
```

inside the Groovy Script or some other alternative

---

EDIT:

I see the [Amazon](https://blog.mikesir87.io/2016/04/pushing-to-ecr-using-jenkins-pipeline-plugin/) version of plugin that can do it, but no sight of GCP one. So I guess good old scripts are the only option.

I think I Know the answer and will just have to create Service Account for it but maybe someone will come with better solution

Comment: To assist further and to get you need from the community, can you provide some code?